# Is there any better way to re-write the below code?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Is there any better way to write the below?

```
    select new
    {
   PaymentId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.PaymentId) ? "" : p.PaymentId,
   AgencyId = String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.AgencyId) ? "" : p.AgencyId,
...............
................
```

Comment: `string.Concat(p.PaymentId)` or `p.PaymentId ?? string.Empty`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure that p is not `null` you could write

```
PaymentId = p.PaymentId ?? "";
```

in case PaymentId would be null, it would return an empty string

Comment: And if p can be null then use: PaymentId = p?.PaymentId ?? "". If p is null this will also return "".

Comment: @RuardvanElburg That would be true in case of C# 6.0, however, he did tag the question as a C# 4.0 question

Answer (score 2):

You could create an Extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static GetValueOrStringEmpty(this string input)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) 
              ? string.Empty 
              : input;
    }
}
```

Then you could refactor your code as below:

```
select new
{
    PaymentId = p.PaymentId.GetValueOrStringEmpty()
    AgencyId =  p.AgencyId.GetValueOrStringEmpty(),
    // ...
}
```

**Disclaimer** the name of the method `GetValueOrStringEmpty` may not be the most suitable. So I suggest you think about a more intuitive name.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use it like this-

```
   select new
    {
      PaymentId = p?.PaymentId ?? string.Empty,
      AgencyId = p?.AgencyId ?? string.Empty,
```

References:

[Null-conditional Operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx)

[null-coalescing operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use null-coalescing operator in C#.

```
   select new
    {
      PaymentId = p.PaymentId ?? string.Empty,
      AgencyId = p.AgencyId ?? string.Empty,
      ................................
      ................................
```